# Tuning max_depth in Random Forest using CARET

Tags: performance, random-forest, caret, depth, overfitting-underfitting

I'm building a Random Forest with Caret package on R with `method = "rf"`. I see that every type of random forest on `caret` seems only tune `mtry` which is the number of features selected randomly for each tree. I do not understand why `max_depth` of each tree is not a tunable parameter (like cart) ? In my mind, it is a parameter which can limit over-fitting.
For example, my rf seems really better on train data than the test data :

```
model <- train(
          group ~., data = train.data, method = "rf",
          trControl = trainControl("repeatedcv", number = 5,repeats =10),
          tuneLength=5
        )


>         postResample(fitted(model),train.data$group)
Accuracy    Kappa 
0.9574592 0.9745841 

>         postResample(predict(model,test.data),test.data$group)
 Accuracy     Kappa 
0.7333333 0.5428571
```

As you can see my model is clearly over-fitted. However, I tried a lot of different things to handle this but nothing worked. I always have something like 0.7 accuracy on test data and 0.95 on train data. This is why I want to optimize other parameters.

*I cannot share my data to reproduce this.*

Comment: How many variables do you have? And also do you see this behaviour if you try different splits of test and train

Comment: I have something between 10 variables but some of them are categoricals. Same results with different splits.